# Is there a finite dimensional subcomplex of the Morse-Bott complex that computes the cohomology of a manifold?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, morse-theory

In the paper Morse-Bott theory and equivariant cohomology, Austin and Braam built the Morse-Bott (geometric) complex which computes the de Rham cohomology of the manifold $M$ (this paper can be found in the Floer Memorial Volume).  This is a generalization of the Morse complex in the case of a Morse-Bott function $f$ on $M$.  However, unlike the Morse complex, the Morse-Bott complex is an infinite dimensional complex.  The chains of the Morse-Bott complex are differential forms on the critical submanifolds of $f$ and the boundary map is defined in terms of the flow lines of the gradient vector fields.  Only when $f$ is Morse is the complex finite dimensional.  I have three related questions:

1. Is there a finite dimensional subcomplex of the Morse-Bott complex that also computes the cohomology of $M$?

The above paper also gave a chain map from the Morse-Bott complex to a certain Morse complex pertaining to a Morse function $f_\epsilon$ obtained from a small perturbation of $f$.  The chain map also induces isomorphism on cohomology (see p.147).  The method is as follows: Let $C_i$ be all the critical submanifolds of $f$, $i=1, ...n$.  Let $f_i$ be a Morse function on $C_i$.  $f_i$ will have critical points on $C_i$.  Let $\rho_i$ be some bump function that has support and value $1$ in some small neighbourhood of $C_i$.  Define for $\epsilon$ small enough, $$f_\epsilon=f+\epsilon\sum\rho_i{{\pi_i}^{-1}}(f_i)$$
Then $f_\epsilon$ is a Morse function on $M$.  (Here $\pi_i$ is projection of the normal bundle to $C_i$.)  Here is my second question:

2. The (finite dimensional) Morse complex obtained from $f_\epsilon$ clearly is not a subcomplex of the Morse-Bott complex.  If there is in question one no finite dimensional subcomplex of the Morse-Bott complex that computes the cohomology of $M$, then the Morse complex of $f_\epsilon$ may be viewed as a finite dimensional substitute.  However, it maybe rather arbitrary, since it depends on the choice of $f_i$.  Also, the dimensions of this complex maybe quite large, for instance, $f_i$ may have more critical points than the sum of the Betti numbers of $C_i$.  That is, $f_i$ may not be a perfect Morse function.  If the Morse complex of $f_\epsilon$ is a substitute, then how to choose a good one?
3. Or are there other ways to construct a finite dimensional "Morse-Bott" complex that computes the cohomology of $M$?